How to set up log level in a docker-compose
I have a docker-compose launching multiple stuff, one of them is prometheus. Issue is, I can't set up the log-level with command as it with break the default entrypoint:
> docker logs 82d94676cc25
ts=2024-06-23T11:44:23.194Z caller=main.go:487 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=prometheus.yml)" file=/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="open prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"

Is there an environment var that I can set up for the logs in the compose? I couldn't find this anywhere.
My current service:
  jeeo-prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.48.1
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"


You can reproduce default parameters in command of your docker compose file: it's only four lines
Based on current config you need something like this:
  jeeo-prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.48.1
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus"
      - "--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries"
      - "--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles"
      - "--log.level=info"


You can add your prometheus targets as prometheus.yml
Then add this docker-compose file .
version: '3.1'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - "./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      - "--log.level=debug"
      - "--log.format=json"


try this:
jeeo-prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.48.1
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug

